# How to watch for new files in Rollup with an array of configs?

Tags: rollupjs

In Rollup you can have a `rollup.config.js` file which either returns a single object or an array of different configs.

```
export default [
  {
    input: 'pages/a.js',
    output: 'dist/a.js',
    // more config options
  },
  {
    input: 'pages/b.js',
    output: 'dist/b.js',
    // more config options
  },
  // etc
]
```

So we can start Rollup's watch feature via `rollup -c -w` and it will trigger a new bundle whenever any of the input files or its dependencies have changed.

Let's go one step further now and instead of manually generating this array of configs we do it by reading the files in the `pages` directory using `fs.readdirSync()`. This makes sense for example in an SSR project where you need to export each page as a single `.js` for rendering HTML in Node.

The problem now is that during watching, Rollup's config will not be triggered if we add a new file into the `pages` directory. So whenever we create a new file we have to start watching again.

Is there a way to solve this via Rollup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think about it, Rollup's config file only exports a static config object/array. How would it know if the config had changed when generated dynamically?

> So we can start Rollup's watch feature via `rollup -c -w` and it will trigger a new bundle whenever any of the input files or its dependencies have changed.

You got this point right, but Rollup **only** re-bundles the input files, it won't regenerate the config. Hence it won't pick up the new files and the exported config will always stay the same.

To answer your question, there's no way to do this via Rollup only. However, you can use [`fs.watch`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) or [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) to watch the `pages` directory, and use [rollup.watch](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#rollupwatch) to programmatically rebuild the config and re-bundle manually.

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten about this question and did end up using a script with chokidar.